# How to get unique values in square brackets from list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, unique

I have a list with this type of values:

```
my_list = [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6), (3,4), (2,1)]
```

I want to get only unique values from there. I also consider (1,2) and (2,1) as same. So desired result is:

```
[(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)]
```

How to do it?

Comment: So what happened when you tried to write code to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty ugly, but here's one solution.

```py
>>> list(set(tuple(set(x)) for x in my_list))
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
```

Converts each `tuple` to a `set`, then back to a `tuple`, collected in an outer `set` to get rid of dupes, then cast back to `list`.

Comment: A variation of this if you like everything to be in order: `sorted(set(tuple(sorted(x)) for x in my_list))`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`more_itertools.unique_everseen`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.unique_everseen) by using `frozenset` as the key:

```
result = list(unique_everseen(my_list, key=frozenset))
```

Comment: Man there are *so* many things in Python's built-in libraries. I really oughta take a look through and get familiar, if only to give better answers on SO lol.

Comment: @blorgon `more_itertools` is not part of the standard library but it's quite popular nevertheless.

Comment: Ah, well now I feel even sillier than before. Please stop making me look bad.